# Adding parameters to @ExceptionHandler for MethodArgumentNotValidException in Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have a Spring controller that validates incoming requests with hibernate validator.

When the request is invalid,  `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is thrown by the validator. Would it be possible to add additional class as an argument to handler method for the exception?

This is what i have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/...", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Response handleCustomObject(@Valid @RequestBody CustomObject obj) {
  //..
}


@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseBody
public Response handleInvalidRequest(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {

    return getMissingMandatoryParametersResponse(e);

    }
}
```

And i would need something like example bellow, however this doesn't work:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseBody
public Response handleInvalidRequest(MethodArgumentNotValidException e, CustomObject obj) {

 // do something with CustomObject
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to do something with the object which failed the validation in the exception handler, you can retrieve it from `BindingResult` like so:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseBody
public Response handleInvalidRequest(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
    CustomObject ce = (CustomObject) e.getBindingResult().getTarget();
    // do something with CustomObject
}
```

You can also take a look at Spring JavaDoc for [`@ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) annotation to see the list of supported exception handler method argument types:

> Handler methods which are annotated with this annotation are allowed
>   to have very flexible signatures. They may have arguments of the
>   following types, in arbitrary order:
>
> - An exception argument: declared as a general Exception or as a more specific exception. This also serves as a mapping hint if the
>     annotation itself does not narrow the exception types through its
>     value().
> - Request and/or response objects (Servlet API or Portlet API). You may choose any specific request/response type, e.g. ServletRequest /
>     HttpServletRequest or PortletRequest / ActionRequest / RenderRequest.
>     Note that in the Portlet case, an explicitly declared action/render
>     argument is also used for mapping specific request types onto a
>     handler method (in case of no other information given that
>     differentiates between action and render requests).
> - Session object (Servlet API or Portlet API): either HttpSession or PortletSession. An argument of this type will enforce the presence of
>     a corresponding session. As a consequence, such an argument will never
>     be null. Note that session access may not be thread-safe, in
>     particular in a Servlet environment: Consider switching the
>     "synchronizeOnSession" flag to "true" if multiple requests are allowed
>     to access a session concurrently.
> - WebRequest or NativeWebRequest. Allows for generic request parameter access as well as request/session attribute access, without
>     ties to the native Servlet/Portlet API.
> - Locale for the current request locale (determined by the most specific locale resolver available, i.e. the configured LocaleResolver
>     in a Servlet environment and the portal locale in a Portlet
>     environment).
> - InputStream / Reader for access to the request's content. This will be the raw InputStream/Reader as exposed by the Servlet/Portlet
>     API.
> - OutputStream / Writer for generating the response's content. This will be the raw OutputStream/Writer as exposed by the Servlet/Portlet
>     API.